# How to apply Lagrange Multipliers with modulus ??

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> I had the question $$x^2+y^2+xy=1$$ and I had to find maximum value of $$\vert xy(x^2+y^2) \vert$$

I tried using Lagrange multipliers by forming

$x^3+3xy^2 = \lambda (2y+x)$
And $y^3+3yx^2 = \lambda (2x+y)$

Now I subtract it to get $(x-y)^3 = \lambda (y-x)$

And as $\lambda ≠ 0 , x=y.$ This gives$ x = {1 \over \sqrt{3}}$ and the expression gives max as $\frac{2}{9}$ but the answer is $2$ . What have I done wrong.

I know it's modulus , but with negative too, there will only be a change in the sign of $\lambda$ which will not affect any working.

Also Lagrange Multipliers is something I read as an extra piece of info online, so maybe I might be missing something trivial here.

Also is there any requirement on $\lambda$ to be positive ??

Comment: If $\lambda\neq0$ then $(x-y)^2=-\lambda$.  If $\lambda=0$ then $x=y$.

Comment: There is no requirement for $\lambda$ to be positive. There isn't even a requirement for $\lambda$ to be non-zero: If the maximum along the restriction is an actual maximum of the function regardless of restriction, then that requires $\lambda = 0$. And @saulspatz If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $x = y$ is still a solution.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I know that.  I was just commenting on the reasoning.

Comment: Also, please spell out "positive" and "negative" rather than writing "+ve" and "-ve". It doesn't take much time, and it makes it more difficult to read. Presumably you want your post to be easy to read, not fast to type.

Comment: @Mr.HiggsBoson What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Find the maximum $M$ and the minimum $m$ of $xy(x^2+y^2)$ on that region. Then:

- If $m\geqslant0$, the maximum of $\bigl\lvert xy(x^2+y^2)\bigr\rvert$ is $M$.
- If $M\leqslant0$, the maximum of $\bigl\lvert xy(x^2+y^2)\bigr\rvert$ is $-m$.
- Otherwise, the maximum of $\bigl\lvert xy(x^2+y^2)\bigr\rvert$ is $\max\bigl\{\lvert M\rvert,\lvert m\rvert\bigr\}$.

Concerning your approach, it seems that you tried to find the maximum of $\bigl\lvert xy(x^2+y^2)\bigr\rvert^2$, which is equal to $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)^2$. It works, but then the system that you will have to solve will be$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2xy^2\left(3x^4+4x^2y^2+y^4\right)=\lambda(2x+y)\\2xy^2\left(3x^4+4x^2y^2+y^4\right)=\lambda(x+2y)\\x^2+y^2+xy=1,\end{array}\right.$$instead of the one that you mentioned. It can be done, but it leads to tougher computations.

Comment: It doesn't address either the fact that the problem has the constraint $x^2+y^2+xy=1$.

Comment: @Arthur Quite right. It is done now (I hope).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I disagree. It was implicit in what I wrote that I was working on that curve.

Comment: Note that any maximum of $\bigl\lvert xy(x^2+y^2)\bigr\rvert$ will coincide with an extremum of $xy(x^2+y^2)$, so there is no actual need for squaring to get rid of the absolute value signs.

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

Following the fact

$$
\max |f| = \max(-f,f) \ \ \text{and}\ \ \min |f| = \min(-f,f)
$$

With $f = x y(x^2+y^2)$ the lagrangian can be established as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda) = s f+\lambda(x^2+y^2+x y -1)
$$

where $s=\pm$

The stationary points are given by

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 2 s y x^2+\lambda  (2 x+y)+s y \left(x^2+y^2\right)&=&0 \\
 2 s x y^2+\lambda  (x+2 y)+s x \left(x^2+y^2\right)&=&0 \\
 x^2+y x+y^2-1 &=&0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving we have

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
s f & x & y \\
 -2 s & -1 & 1 \\
 -2 s & 1 & -1 \\
 \frac{2 s}{9} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
 \frac{2 s}{9} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

Due to its homogeneity the problem, using $y = \mu x$, can be transformed into one without restrictions as

$$
f(\mu) = \frac{\mu(1+\mu^2)}{(1+\mu+\mu^2)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative and geometric way of examining the problem:

$$x^2+y^2+xy=1$$ 
Is the equation of an ellipse whose major axis is supported by the line $y=-x$.

Note that $xy(x^2+y^2)=(1-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)=k$ solves to $$x^2+y^2=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4k}}2=\phi_{\pm}(k)$$

[image]

This is a circle of radius $\phi_{\pm}(k)^{\frac 12}$.

- Purple circle $\phi_-(k)$ for $k\in[0,\frac 14]$

is not interesting because it gives a circle which is strictly inside the ellipsis (max radius $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$ is when $k=\frac 14$ which is smaller than minor axis of ellipse).

- Green circle on the other hand $\phi_+(k)$ intersects with the ellipse

and gives a growing circle when $k\to-\infty$.

Make $k$ vary in this simulation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/41c7utwiy3

The maximum value of $|xy(x^2+y^2)|=-k$ is obtained for the circumcircle of the ellipse, whose radius is given by the major axis extension.

On the major axis $y=-x$ and it is easy to find that $x=\pm 1$ and $k=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

You found by subtracting 
$$
(x-y)^3=λ(y-x).
$$
In the same way you can add the two equations to get
$$
(x+y)^3=3λ(x+y)
$$
As @saulspatz commented, you got the cases mixed up,  $λ\ne0$ does not force $x=y$. Correct is

- if $λ=0$ then $x-y=0=x+y$, which has only the trivial solution $x=y=0$ with objective value $0$.
- if $λ\ne0$ then $(x-y)^2=-λ$ or $x=y$ and also either $(x+y)^2=3λ$ or $x+y=0$. As a square of a real number is always positive, only the crossed variants give new extremal points.

  - $x=y$: the constraint reduces to $3x^2=1$, which results in $x=y=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$, which you already found with objective value $|xy(x^2+y^2)|=\frac29$.
  - $x=-y$: the constraint reduces to $x^2=1$, which results in $x=-y=\pm1$ with objective value $|xy(x^2+y^2)|=2$.

Comment: How will I know that wether I really have reached the absolute maximum of this value, that is, how can I be sure that this really is the maximum and no other combination will lead to another relation in x,y which will yeild even a bigger result.

Comment: As you have a smooth objective over a smooth compact curve, the extrema have to be at critical points. Thus if you enumerate all the critical points, you will also get the full range of possible values.

Comment: I'm not particularly asking for this particular case, but in general with any question.

Comment: Then you also can have extrema at the boundaries (or infinity if that does not count as boundary). Thus you have to explore each face and facet of the boundary for critical points and include them in the enumeration of local extrema.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to eliminate $\lambda$ from the vector equation
$$
(x^3+3xy^2,y^3+3yx^2)=\lambda(2x+y,x+2y)
$$
by calculating it as a ratio in the two obvious ways, and equating them. The result is the equation
$$
(x^3+2xy^2)(x+2y)=(y^3+3yx^2)(2x+y).
$$
As Cesareo pointed out, this is homogeneous, and solving it gives
$$
x=y,\quad x=-y,\quad y=(2-\sqrt3)x,\quad y=(2+\sqrt3)x
$$
as possibilities. In other words, four lines through the origin. I trust you to be able to find the intersection of these lines and the ellipse $x^2+xy+y^2=1$, list the points, and find the maximum.